# Grep, find line with minimum x words

Tags: linux, find, grep, awk

Is there a way to find all lines with grep, that contains at least **x** words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, assuming words are separated by spaces, to find lines with >= 5 words, do this:

```
$ grep -P '\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+'
```

Grep is not the best tool for the job though, try gawk:

```
$ gawk 'NF>4'
```

Gawk's NF variable holds the number of fields, by default fields are defined by spaces, so in a line of text each field is a word. The command above will print all lines containing more than 4 words.

Comment: But words can also be separated by comma. And at the end of the sentence there is dot. I try this:    grep -E "(\w+[ ,.]+){25,}"   and it seems to work allright.

Comment: My gawk command counts fields @quin61, three spaces means four fields. The dot is irrelevant and, in normal text, there is a space after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the number "3" if you want lines >= to a different value.

```
grep -E '^(\w+\b.){3}'
```